# adding dynamic divs inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the code bellow to add dynamic divs with some attributes but the code doesnt work.

```
<div id="divsholder"></div>

var num = "4";
var container = $('<div />');
for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
container.append('<div id="mystyle" class="pic'+i+'" />');
}
$('#divsholder').html(container);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you just can't *see* anything because there is no text contents?

Comment: [Your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/wmPqQ/). Keep in mind that `id` attribute should be unique across all DOM elements!

Comment: i chanched my code to this and it's working now: 
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
$('#button_container').append('<div id="thestyle_btns" class="pic'+i+'" />'); 
}

Comment: Be careful about using strings for values that should be numbers. I.e., use `var num = 4;` rather than `var num = "4";`.

Comment: @IreneT. your earlier code was working too! http://jsfiddle.net/ETCVm/1/

Comment: @IreneT.: you are still doing the same mistake. your are keeping the `id` same but making the `class` different. it should be the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this using jQueries "`APPEND`" function
Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/somdow/9A6DA/2/

With this example, i made it so that when the p tags reach 4, for it to alert the user.
You can add whatever you want to happen after the 4th event etc.

css:

```
#mainW{width:200px; background:#f00; text-align:center;}
.blu{ background-color:blue; }
```

html:

```
<div id="mainW">
    <a href="#"> content here,</a><br/>

</div>
```

here is the code required for the jsfiddle.
js/jq

```
$('#mainW a').click(function(){

    $('#mainW').append( "<p>Test</p>" );

    if( $('p').length == 4 ){ alert("lopan")}
});
```

Comment: The OP's code is _already_ using jQuery's `.append()` function. If you mean she should use `.append()` instead of `.html()` you should make that more clear by showing an improved version of her code, not some completely new code.

Comment: When i saw the OPS "any ideas?" i figured it could be shorter and write it up real fast. But you are right lol

Comment: It worked like this: for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++) { $('#button_container').append('<div id="thestyle_btns" class="pic'+i+'" />');  }  But how can now add inside the each div the looped number? <div id="thestyle_btns" etc>'+i+'</div> ?

Comment: Solved: to display each number as html at divs i used: for(var s = 1; s <= count; s++) {
$('.pic'+s).html(s);
}

Answer (score 1):

Your code working perfect

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divsholder"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = "4";
    var container = $('<div />');
    for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        container.append('<div id="mystyle" class="pic'+i+'" />');
    }
    $('#divsholder').html(container);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code result

```
<div id="divsholder"><div><div id="mystyle" class="pic1"></div><div id="mystyle" class="pic2"></div><div id="mystyle" class="pic3"></div><div id="mystyle" class="pic4"></div></div></div>
```

ID element maybe one and unique. If you use more than one ID use class="class-name"

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but the ending HTML results into the following:

```
 ---divsholder----------------------
 |                                 |
 |  -- a div with no name ------   |
 |  |                          |   |
 |  |  --divs from for loop--  |   |
 |  |  |                    |  |   |
 |  |  |                    |  |   |
 |  |  ----------------------  |   |
 |  |                          |   |
 |   ---------------------------   |
 |                                 |
 -----------------------------------
```

So the problem might arise from the fact that you are placing the `divs` into another div un-intentionally.

I have modified your code so that you can clearly see the problem visually here

http://jsfiddle.net/xCr5C/